# Filter RestAPI JSON output values for github enterprise url

Tags: json, curl, postman, github-api

While using `https://githubenterprise.example.com/api/v3/authorizations` to get all informations from the github enterprise server, getting output as expected.

But, while trying to add filter to sort specific field with below url, it wont work and display all content always.
`https://githubenterprise.example.com/api/v3/authorizations?filter=id=564`

Tried with curl as well as postman but no luck.
`curl -u myuser https://githubenterprise.example.com/api/v3/authorizations?id=564`

Can anyone please help me?